# responsive text using vw does not display correctly when using control - and +

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am building a site using vw to make the fonts responsive but it will not work when I use control - or control + to enlarge or reduce the size of the site. Instead the font remains the same size.

Using em, the font is reduced when hitting control - or + but on browsers with different displacement the font remains the same while the other features are responsive, causing problems.

Is there a way around this issue to get the fonts responsive and still have control - and + to work?

Comment: please share us your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`vw` wont work when pressing `ctrl +`  or `ctrl -` since `vw` means **viewport's width**, so the size depends on the width of your current browser.

The way to make font responsive is setting its sized manually depending on certain **browsers width** using the css `@media` queries. [@media Rule](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

`ctrl +` and `ctrl -` would also work in that way.

Comment: Is it better to use VW to make text responsive or to make a series of media queries using REM to make text responsive, enabling control - and control +, which would add a large amount of css code? Is it necessary to enable control + and - at all? Can they be disabled with code in the site?

Comment: i think i would be better to use `vw` instead to lessen css codes. If your font size is readable enough, ctrl - and + wont be necessary.

with disabling the ctrl - & +. Yes its posible.

Comment: How can I disable ctrl - and + with Wordpress? I have searched and can find no solution that will work.

Comment: With the wordpress. maybe try seaching wordpress plugins like [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-content-copy-protection/).  btw, can u accept the answer?

Comment: I have found a great solution to disable ctrl - and ctrl +, thanks for your help!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "can u accept the answer?", I am new to this site

Comment: You're welcome.  Can see a check icon in the left under the thing with arrows like:  "⇧ 0⇩ "?